# Trying to create a sql query using checkboxes

Tags: php, sql

I'm a bit of a beginner at sql but I believe this should work. I'm doing it step by step so this isn't the complete code yet but I've hit a problem. Basically what I'm trying to do is use the array created from the form:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="features[]" value="Texture" >Textures<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="features[]" value="Items" >Items<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="features[]" value="GUI" >Gui<br />
</form
```

And create what will be end up being a query for my database. Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

    $button = $_POST['submit'];
    $features = $_POST['features'];

    if ($button){

    //connect
    mysql_connect("server","username","password");
    mysql_select_db("rdm");

    foreach ($features){

    $x++;

    if ($x=1)
    $construct .= "feature LIKE '$features[$x]'";
    else
    $construct .= " OR feature LIKE '$features[$x]'";
    }

    $construct = "SELECT * FROM Textures WHERE '$construct';

    echo $construct;

    ?>
```

My understanding is this should echo out the variable $construct, which will contain the text "SELECT * FROM Textures WHERE feature LIKE ... and then the first value in the features array, followed by the other values.

Any help as to why this isn't working would be fantastic! As I say, I'm pretty new to this so sorry if this is a silly mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot your closing double-quote on the line before your echo.

Comment: You have incorrect syntax on your `foreach`.

Comment: You have an unmatched brace from `if ($button){`

Comment: As a side note, I guess you should escape your input values: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: You're assigning a value with `if ($x=1)` instead of comparing values.

Comment: it might be easier to throw the LIKE statements into an array, and then use implode() to fill-in the OR's.

Answer (score 3):

Your query string will be generated wrong:

```
if ($x=1)
```

This isn't a comparison, it's setting x to 1, so your query will have no 'OR' conditions in it. A better method to do your query generation is:

```
$query_conditions = array()
foreach($_POST['features'] as $feature) {
     $query_conditions[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($feature) . "'"
}
$where_in_clause = implode(',', $query_conditions);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Textures WHERE feature IN ($where_in_clause)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// implode the features array into a string, adding quotes
$featuresString = "'".implode("','", $features)."'";
// build the query
$construct = "SELECT * FROM Textures WHERE feature IN (".$featuresString.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of syntax errors in there.  Notably, the line with SQL does not close the double quote or use a semi-colon at the end of the line.  There is also a missing bracket at the end of your `if` block.

This code will accomplish the task as stated:

```
$button = isset($_POST['submit']) ? true : false;
$features = isset($_POST['features']) ? $_POST['features'] : false;

if ($button && is_array($features)) {
        $construct = 'SELECT * FROM Textures WHERE feature IN  ("'.implode('","', $features ).'")';
    echo $construct;
}
```